# How to Assign id dynamically in JSf to Datatable column

Tags: jsf, datatable

Hi please check below code for your reference.

```
                                    <%
                                        System.out.println("Here???????? 111111 :::::::::::::: "+request.getAttribute("COLUMNSIZE"));

                                        if(request.getAttribute("COLUMNSIZE") != null){

                                            int columnSize = 0;
                                            columnSize = Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("COLUMNSIZE").toString());
                                            System.out.println("Here 111111 :::::::::::::: "+columnSize);

                                            for(int loop=0 ; loop < columnSize ; loop++){
                                    %>

                                    <h:column>
                                        <f:facet name="header" >
                                            <h:outputText value="Field <%=loop%>">
                                            </h:outputText>
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <h:outputText value="Password" />
                                    </h:column>

                                    <%
                                        }
                                        }
                                    %>

                                </h:dataTable>
```

Now what i want to is that I want to assign id to column dynamically using loop variable ... but scriplets is not allowed and I cant found any other way for it.

So if any of you have idea about it then please reply me quickly.

Comment: Removed unnecessary tags, you can modify if not proper

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question right you want to change the number of columns of your dataTable dynamically (I may be wrong).

If you're on icefaces or richfaces why don't you make use of `ice:columns` or `rich:columns`?

Comment: i am not on either of it .. m using pure JSF

Comment: so why do you use richfaces / icefaces tags? Btw. a comfortable way to achieve this is using a component library (like rich-/ice-/primefaces)

Answer (score 0):

Scriplets shouldn't be mixed up with JSF expressions. Below code can be used to achieve what you already trying, placing logic in backing bean & looks more readable.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{backingBean.headerNames}" var="header">
                 <li> 
                      <h:outputText value="#{header.field}" />
                 </li> 
</ui:repeat>
```

For further details, go through [JSF EL Documentation](http://developers.sun.com/docs/jscreator/help/jsp-jsfel/jsf_expression_language_intro.html)

Comment: I Tries the way you said but its giving following error <h:column id="field#{param['loop']}"> -- Syntax   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/timesascentadmin].[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Subsequent characters of component identifier must be a letter, a digit, an underscore ('_'), or a dash ('-')! But component identifier contains "#"

Comment: Edited answer to achieve the same but with facelets.

Answer (score 0):

May be its work.

```
HtmlOutputText test = new HtmlOutputText();
test.setValue("test");

HtmlDataTable dataTable = new HtmlDataTable();
dataTable.getChildren().add(test);
```